# Visual Studio - Cannot find JDK

Tags: java, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I am currently experiencing an issue with Visual Studio 2022 (Happens on 2019 as well),
whenever I create a new Xamarin project, I get these errors.

[image]

When I try to configure the existing JDK installation to point to another JDK it does not work. Using the default installed OpenJdk does not work either

[image]

Here I am trying to point it to the exisiting JDK that was installed along Visual Studio.
I also tried **jdk 8** and **openjdk 11 13.8.1**.
I tried changing the **JAVA_HOME** to point to the appropriate JDK as well, but to no avail.

Under Tools -> Options -> Xamarin, I have this
[image]

I am unable to do anything with the "Java  Development Kit Location", if I try to point it to any JDK location it will tell me "Cannot find Java Development Kit files in specified path"

The android SDK location points to the SDK that VS installed during the setup.

I have on several occasions tried uninstalling everything related to VS on my computer, but it still did not work

I have tried (not in order):

- Repaired Visual Studio as the IDE recommends (in order to use the default OpenJdk)
- Installing OpenJDK and setting the correct PATH and JAVA_HOME prior to installing Visual Studio
- Installed the appropriate JDK after installing Visual Studio
- Installing Visual Studio without having JDK on my computer and letting Visual Studio set the PATH to the default installed OpenJdk
- Installing OpenJDK and letting the JDK set the PATH itself
- Turning off all malware protection and Windows Firewall before installing Visual Studio
- I have always checked "javac" and "echo &JAVA_HOME% in the CMD in order to see if everything is working as it should
- Changing the PATH(s) to point to \bin in the JDK folder

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Uninstall all Java Jdk and reinstall jdk 1.8 latest and set path then restart Visual studio.it will start working.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT Sadly this did not fix the issue. Visual Studio finds the correct path, but complains that it could not find "the required jar". Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Check this guide about setting android sdk on vs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows

And here is the guide about updating jdk in vs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/update-jdk?tabs=windows

If you done both and nothing changed  you can report the issue as following shows :[image]

Comment: This did not work either, I will report the issue. Thank you Adrain!